# Meaning of “帶看病做工!她的一家人還是餓看！“?

Tags: translation

Stumped on this intertitle for a silent movie. When a woman faints, two men come to her aid. The first one says to the second:

“帶看病做工!她的一家人還是餓看！“

I can't parse the parts into a coherent whole:

帶看病: "Bring see doctor" - is that a request for a doctor, or an explanation that she was on her way to see the doctor?

做工: "do work" - who works, doctor or woman? Or is she working to earn money to see doctor?

她的一家人: "Her entire family"

還是餓看: Don't get this at all, particularly 餓看. "prefer to go hungry than see a doctor", maybe? Or "still are hungry"?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"看" in “帶看病做工!她的一家人還是餓看！“ is obviously a typo of "着"

> “帶着病做工, 她的一家人還是餓着“ would make all the sense

**帶着病**做工 = working **with illness** (working while she is sick)

還是**餓着** = is still **in hunger** (餓= hungry; 餓着 = in a continuous state of hungry)

Comment: Bingo!! Problem was my misreading of the character. This quick answer made my day - thanks!